# Aligning text vertically within a link using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create 3 buttons that are side by side at the top of my page. When the page gets smaller they should stack. So far that's fine. I have my buttons. I'm trying to set the height of the buttons to 50px max when full-screen. The problem is when I set my height, the text in my buttons don't center vertically.

Here's what I have so far:

```
.flx-search {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;


  width:1060px;
  color:#ffffff;
}

.flx-search-item {
  flex-grow:1;
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  flex: 0 0 350px;
  height:50px;
}

<div style="background-color:#34495e;display:flex; justify-content:center;">
  <div class="flx-search">
     <a class="flx-search-item">Search Our Catalog</a>
     <a class="flx-search-item">View Patron Record</a>
     <a class="flx-search-item">Register for Programs</a>  
  </div>
</div>
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c60t2r2k/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your flex item a nested flex container, and then use flex properties to center the text.

In other words, apply `display: flex` to `.flx-search-item`.

```
.flx-search-item {
     display: flex;            /* new */
     align-items: center;      /* new */
     justify-content: center;  /* new */

     flex-grow: 1;
     text-align: center;
     /* display: block; <-- remove this */
     flex: 0 0 350px;
     height: 50px;
  }
```

[**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/c60t2r2k/2/)

Remove `display: block` or it will override `display: flex`.

Also, `flex-grow: 1` is being overridden by `flex: 0 0 350px`, which is the shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, `flex-basis`.

If you want `flex-grow: 1`, get rid of that line and just use `flex: 1 0 350px`.

Comment: I applied it, but 1 thing. Is there a way to make the height scale as the page shrinks?

Comment: For the scaling, yes. You could use [**viewport units**](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/). For the hovering, you were targeting the wrong parent: [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/c60t2r2k/3/) (re-size window horizontally for scaling effect; hovering works).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was just wondering if there was a way to do it without media queries

Comment: As you can see, no media queries :-)

Comment: i mean for the height resizing of the items. they are 50px... they don't change with scale

Comment: You could also use viewport units on the flex items. https://jsfiddle.net/c60t2r2k/4/

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line-height:50px; to .flx-search-item.

EDIT (sample with @media query) :

```
.flx-search-item {
     text-align: center;
     flex: 0 0 350px;
     height: 50px;
     line-height: 50px;
}

@media (max-width:1065px) {
    .flx-search-item
    {
        flex: 0 0 700px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:710px) {
    .flx-search-item
    {
        flex: 0 0 350px;
    }
}
```

Comment: problem with that is when it shrinks, the height remains 50px instead of shrinking and the text becomes off centered vertically

Comment: Ok. In fact, it seems that all three buttons are centered vertically, but displayed on 2 lines when available space is between 700 and 1050px. You can use @media query to solve this case.